# Does this CSS effect have a name?

Tags: css

Does this kind of tutorial effect have a name? I couldn't find the words such as your board,  your pins, etc. in the drop down menu.

[image: css]

Comment: Which part are you referring to? The dimmed page?

Comment: The question does not describe any effect. Besides, asking for names of effects is hardly a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word you're looking for is **"modal"**.

It refers to the content on the top of the page being in focus, and the content beneath it inaccessible.

Typically, if you were searching Google, you might find something useful by searching for *modal dialog*, but the process can be applied to any content.

It is achieved with CSS, by applying an opaque black background overlay and adding a high `z-index` to the focusable content.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the [modal dialog](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html) the other "effects" remind me of the [joyride](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/joyride.html) script, or 
a [dynamic grid](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/) script. However these can be achieved using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

From your statement `I couldn't find the words such as your board, your pins, etc. in the drop down menu.` I am assuming that you are referring towards the stacked free-height tiles layout like the one [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/) have ?

**If yes**

Than have a look at [Masonry `Cascading grid layout` library](http://masonry.desandro.com/)